# How can I correctly write code in C language to accept input containing spaces in between and ending with a newline?

Tags: arrays, c, string, struct

here is my input:

```
3
Programming in C
21.5
Programming in VB
18.5
Programming in Delphi
25.0
```

and here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
struct book{
    char name[30];
    double price;
};
int main(){
    int i,n,max=0,min=0;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    struct book bo[10];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        fgets(bo[i].name,sizeof(bo[i].name),stdin);
        strtok(bo[i].name,"\n");
        scanf("%lf\n",&bo[i].price);
        if(bo[i].price>bo[max].price)
            max=i;
        if(bo[i].price<bo[min].price)
            min=i;
    }

    printf("%.2f, %s\n",bo[max].price,bo[max].name);
    printf("%.2f, %s",bo[min].price,bo[min].name);
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know why i always get the operation answer like:
21.50, Programming in C
0.00,

I have try to use “fgets” to read the spaces
and use "strtok" like
`strtok(bo[i].name,"\n");`
or "strcspn"  like
`bo[i].name[strcspn(bo[i].name,"\n")]='\0';`
to replace '\n' with '\0',but it is still incorret.

Comment: The first `fgets` will read an empty line because of the newline left in the buffer after `scanf("%d",&n);`. The `\n` in the `scanf` inside the loop could potentially be replaced with `%*c` and would work as long as there is no trailing space in the input, only a newline after the number. Personally I try to not mix `scanf` and `fgets`, I'd just use `fgets` to read a line and `sscanf` to convert the numbers.

Comment: If you do use functions like `scanf` that can fail you absolutely need to check the return value from them to detect that and handle it accordingly.

Comment: Off topic: Years working in the business and I've **never ever** heard of someone being charged for using the spacebar to make their code readable. On topic: What should the program do if two-or-more books of the same price are the most (or least) expensive on the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to clear the newline from the stdin steam after reading number field (`n` and `price`) before reading a string after `name`).  I used `scanf("%*[\n]")` below.  I switched to using `scanf()` to read a line of text to show you a different option than the other options.

Another really good option is to read a line of input with `gets()` or `getline()` then use `sscanf()` to parse that line of text.  This separates I/O and parsing.

In any case always check the return value from I/O calls otherwise you may be operating on uninitialized variables.  Instead of hard-coding the number of records use a variable length array (vla) but check that the number of records are reasonable.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define NAME_LEN 29
#define str(s) str2(s)
#define str2(s) #s

// increase as needed
#define MAX_N 10

struct book{
    char name[NAME_LEN+1];
    double price;
};

int main(void) {
    int n;
    if(scanf("%d", &n) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed reading number of records\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if(scanf("%*[\n]") != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed reading number of records terminator\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if(n <= 0 || n > MAX_N) {
        fprintf(stderr, "too few or too many records\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int max=0;
    int min=0;
    struct book bo[n];
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        if(scanf("%" str(NAME_LEN) "[^\n]", bo[i].name) != 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed reading name\n");
            return 1;
        }
        if(scanf("%lf", &bo[i].price) != 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "failed reading price\n");
            return 1;
        }
        if(scanf("%*[\n]") != 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "failed reading price terminator\n");
            return 1;
        }
        // pick first book if several have the same price;
        // use >= or <= if you want the last.  If you want
        // to keep all then you need to keep an array of 
        // worst case min[n] and max[n] values.
        if(bo[i].price>bo[max].price)
            max=i;
        if(bo[i].price<bo[min].price)
            min=i;
    }
    printf("%.2f, %s\n", bo[min].price, bo[min].name);
    printf("%.2f, %s\n", bo[max].price, bo[max].name);
    return 0;
}
```

and output:

```
$ ./a.out < input.txt
18.50, Programming in VB
25.00, Programming in Delphi
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use scanf to read the number of books, it leaves a newline character in the buffer. It's like leaving crumbs behind. fgets then reads this newline as if it's the actual input, which results in an empty string for the book name.

To fix this, use getchar() right after scanf. This will clean up the newline, like sweeping the crumbs off the table. Do this again after reading the book price with scanf.

For the newline at the end of the book name added by fgets, use strcspn to trim it off.

Comment: `fgets()` does not **add** a LF to the buffer...

Comment: The `fgets()` function includes the newline at the end of the buffer if there is enough room, but it doesn't "add" a newline if there isn't one to be read.  It's a small matter of precision in wording.

Answer (score 0):

- Do not mix `fgets()` with `scanf()` until you understand why it is bad.  Best to only use `fgets()` for now.
- Do not use `strtok(buffer, "\n")`.  It fails to remove the `'\n'` when buffer is `"\n"`.
- `fgets(bo[i].name,sizeof(bo[i].name),stdin);` fails to read a maximal length name into `.name` as input may contain a `'\n'` and the entire line should be read.  Instead:

```
char buf[2 * sizeof bo[i].name + 1];
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) {
  Handle_no_input();
}
buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = 0;
if (strlen(buf) >= sizeof bo[i].name) {
  Handle_too_long_input();
}
strcpy(bo[i].name, buf);
```